# need to add or remove menu icons in favorites page in iphone app?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I have 20 buttons.Need to add and remove buttons from UIView dynamically with scrollview.

eg:

```
 ![from this image  click star buttons to remove or add buttons.][1]


     https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnRxG.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the property `tag`. It's an integer that you can use to identify view objects in your application.

```
@property(nonatomic) NSInteger tag
```

**Sample code to add:**

```
UIButton *btnOk = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50)];
[btnOk setTag:100];
//add target and set other properties here.
[self.view addSubview:btnOk];
btnOk = nil;
```

**Sample code to Remove:**

```
UIButton *btnOk =  [[self.view viewWithTag:100] isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]?(UIButton *)[self.view viewWithTag:100]:nil;
[btnOk removeFromSuperview];
```